# Javascript: append script with an object, and create a local instance

Tags: javascript, scope, append, global, local

Let me expose my question:
I have a main script, let's say that it creates an instance of a "game" object, which, depending on the actions of the user, loads one of many javascript files, let's call them "levels" :D These files contains different objects, for example, "level1.js" which contains the object for level1, then "level2.js", etc.

Each time a level script is loaded, for example level1.js, the instance of "game" creates an instance of the object level1 and stores it in a local variable.

The only way I've found to do it, is to write, at the end of all the "level" scripts, a global variable, which has always the same name, and that points to the definition of the current level. Then in game, when any level script is loaded, I use this global variable to create the instance of the current level. I would like to know if there is a way to do it without using a global variable.

Here is a simplified example:

In game.js:

```
function Game() {
    var levelCurrent = null;
    var scriptCour = document.createElement("script");

    scriptCur.type = "text/javascript";
    scriptCur.onload = function() {
         levelCurrent = new level();
    }
}
```

And in each "level" script (level1.js, level2.js):

```
function level1() {
    //definition of the level
    //...
}
level = level1;
```

Or, similarly:

```
level = function() {
    //definition of the level
    //...
}
```

I don't know if I explained well enough my question, but if anyone has an answer... Thank you! Note that the instance of game is created using a self-executing function, and is therefore a local variable, like:

```
(function() {
    var game = new Game();
})();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Concerning using: `var level = function()...`, it seems that if it is defined outside any object, it will be the same as a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning the new level to a global variable, you should call a global function with the level information, e.g.

```
window.addLevel(function level1() {
    //definition of the level
    //...
});
```

Why is your Game instance a local variable, can't it be accessed? I guess it's a singleton (only one instance), so it would be perfectly valid to have it as a global variable. It then would be a good namespace for the addLevel function (`window.game.addLevel()`).

Comment: Yes I have only one instance of Game, but I made it a local instance following [these recommandations](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18D-9N-VtEk5CsYAHJGkDq6l2H-GubAo63Aq3Rb46ThQ/edit?pli=1) It's not a big security, but it prevents common users to use the console to alter the properties. But here, I checked, I have no public properties in the game object. Your idea seems great, but it requires global access to the variable levelCurrent isn't it? Thanks!

Comment: OK, the properties of a play shouldn't be (global) accessible, but the game engine might (and should) have a public interface (e.g. addLevel, startLevel, showHighscore - not the editable Highscore object itself).

Answer (score 0):

You could have the main game code expose a single global function, like "startNewLevel" or something, and then instead of declaring a global variable you'd just have the new level pass itself to that function.